# Searching Multiple Results using Streamreader

Tags: vb.net

Does anyone know of a method that allows you to search a string through a text file using StreamReader that allows you to account for multiple instances of finding the results. Basically I am creating a booking application and each time a customer books a seat, their PrimaryKey, FirstName, LastName and the co-ordinates of the seat on a data grid (which I have used as a method to book seats) are generated then saved to a text file.

I want the ability to be able to read multiple instances of a PrimaryKey then find the seat co-ordinates of each line that this PrimaryKey is listed on and repopulate another similar datagridview with these co-ordinates which is all going to be driven by a combobox index change.

It seems a bit complicated to understand but if anyone can help then please let me know.

I just need the knowhow of how to search multiple instances, so after its found the string once then look through the rest of the file to find another instance, I can do the rest by myself.

I'm coding using Visual Basic.Net

Comment: You don't want to use an unstructured file for that. Load it all up if it's not to too big, Load up and index to the file. A memory mapped file, lots' of ways to do this. Even if you stick with a straight text file, that doesn't mean you have to access it that way.

Comment: Yeah but how do I go about searching multiple times through a text file without using any other type of file? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to search multiple times through a file, but you'd either have to reopen the file, or rewind the stream (FileStream.Seek).
Wildly inefficient though.
If it has to remain an unsorted and unstructured file, build an in memory index to it.

If your key is an integer, create a `Dictionary<int,int>` of Key and Position in the stream.
Then when you want find key X you use `FileStream.Seek` to move to it, and read a line to get the data. If you find yourself grouping by say aeroplaneID, build a `Dictionary<Int, List<Int,Int>>`
where the key is the aeroplane id and the list is a list of primary keys and positions in the file.

You could push all that off to a background thread. You could try and get really clever and build them up as you need them. Personally though I'd be trying to move my storage to a more suitable format. You aren't struggling to do this because you've missed a class, you are struggling because you shouldn't.

Something like

```
Dictionary<int, int> _fileIndex = new Dictionary<int,int>();
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(DataFileName,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
   int lastPosition = 0;
   string currentLine = null;
   while(currentLine = reader.ReadLine() != null)
   {
      String[] data = currentLine.Split(new char[] {','});
      int key = int.Parse(data[0]);
      fileIndex.Add(key,lastPosition);
      lastPosition = fs.Position;
   }
}
```

NB didn't test the above and there should be a bit more error checking in it. If there's alot of data in the line, then might be better off not suing split and just pulling out everything up to the correct delimiter. Also be careful how many indexes you keep live, wouldn't be long before they used up more space than just reading the entire thing in to memory.

Then you could create a class or structure to implement a line in the file, and write a bit of code
to use FileStream.Seek) to get there. If you wanted to load up a bunch of 'em it would make sense to get your list of positions of each one in the file and then sort them in order, then you could rip through the file in it's 'order' picking them out.

Comment: Could you maybe write this code in Visual Basic instead of C#?

Comment: I've used a converter to convert your code to VB.Net and fileIndex doesn't seem to be a correct command

Comment: I need to be able to locate multiple occurrences of a string within a text file which has multiple lines, So each time it finds the string it locates another piece of information on that line that I need so that I can populate a datagridview correctly. I don't know if you understand what I mean

Comment: _fileIndex is a variable. And your question was about the problems with having to read a text file multiple times. Based in your comment if you wanted to do that and not have to read the file multiple times. You would adapt use the grouping idea and the key would be this here keyword. Unless you know every key word that could be searched there's not alot you can do about re-reads.

Comment: PS apologies, didn't spot the VB.Net tag.

Comment: You might be better off detailing your problem in an other question, instead of asking about a symptom. People are going to want to see whet you've tried though.